# Install GTM in pure javascript through functions.php

Tags: javascript

[GTM documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) says to include two snippets, 1 after `<head>` opening tag and 1 after `<body>` opening tag.
Initially I was adding the snippets in my child's header.php file.
I wanted to drop that method and use plain JS instead, mainly because of parent theme updates.

I wrote the code below to use in functions.php, but it doesn't work and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit** : error I'm getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null` for `document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.firstChild);`

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'webplus_hook_gtm' );
function webplus_hook_gtm() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var para = document.createElement("script");
    var t = document.createTextNode(
    "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');"
    );
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.head.insertBefore(para, document.head.firstChild);

    var el = document.createElement("noscript");
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
    );
    ifrm.setAttribute("height", "0");
    ifrm.setAttribute("width", "0");
    ifrm.setAttribute("style", "display:none;visibility:hidden");
    el.appendChild(ifrm);
    document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.firstChild);
</script>
<?php
};
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated, TIA.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful.  Please try to include as many details as possible.  What isn't working?  What JS errors do you have?  etc

Comment: Does your theme use `wp_head` in header? Does it use the new `wp_body_open`?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? GTM error? Console?

Comment: @all, sorry for lack of information about error on initial post and thank you for pointing it out.
Could it be possible because I try to add the noscript after body opening tag in a `wp_head` function since body comes after </head> tag ? (thanks to @KrzysiekDróżdż comment which made me look at it).
@KrzysiekDróżdż yes, my theme uses `wp_body_open()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code is inside the `<head>` element, but the code is trying to access `document.body` which won't exist at the time that your script is run. If I recall correctly you're *supposed* to place this code immediately after the opening `<body>` tag. To do this from functions.php your theme needs to support the [new `wp_body_open()` hook](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2019/03/29/addition-of-new-wp_body_open-hook/).

**header.php:**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'webplus_hook_gtm' );
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob, yes my theme supports `wp_body_open()`. There is 2 codes to insert, one right after <head> opening tag, another right after <body> opening tag.
I need indeed to split my `function webplus_hook_gtm()` in 2 separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your contributions which helped me to understand my mistake and solve my issue, especially  @Krzysiek Dróżdż for the hint and @Jacob for partial solution with the action. This is my working final code :

```php
    <?php

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'webplus_hook_gtm' );
    function webplus_hook_gtm() {
        ?>
        <script>
            var para = document.createElement("script");
            var t = document.createTextNode(
            "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');"
            );
            para.appendChild(t);
            document.head.insertBefore(para, document.head.firstChild);
        </script>
        <?php
    };

    add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'webplus_hook_gtm_noscript' );
    function webplus_hook_gtm_noscript() {
        ?>
        <script>
            var el = document.createElement("noscript");
            var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
            ifrm.setAttribute(
            "src",
            "https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
            );
            ifrm.setAttribute("height", "0");
            ifrm.setAttribute("width", "0");
            ifrm.setAttribute("style", "display:none;visibility:hidden");
            el.appendChild(ifrm);
            document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.firstChild);
        </script>
        <?php
    };
```